# Question on proof of uniqueness of product measure in Bartle

Tags: measure-theory

I quote this theorem from Elements of Integration and Lebesgue measure:
$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}\newcommand{\Y}{\mathcal{Y}}$

> If (X,$\X$,$\mu$) and $(Y,\Y,\nu)$ are measure spaces, then there exists a measure $\pi$ defined on $Z=X\times Y$ such that $\pi(A\times B) = \mu(A)\nu(B)$ for all $A\in \X$ and $B\in \Y$. If these measure spaces a $\sigma$-finite, then there is a unique measure $\pi$ with such a property.

I don't really understand the proof of the uniqueness. It goes as follows: Let $Z_0$ be the algebra generated by rectangles. Let $Z$ denote the sigma algebra generated by the rectangles, and let $Z^*$ denote the sigma algebra of subsets of $X\times Y$ satisfying the caratheodory condition. Therefore, we have $Z_0\subset Z\subset Z^*$. The Hahn extension gives us that there is a unique measure which extends the measure on $Z_0$ to $Z^*$. However, I don't see why this means that any extension of the measure to $Z$ must be unique as well. Is it not possible that there can be more than one measure on $Z$, but due to the additional number of subsets in $Z^*$, more conditions are imposed for the sigma-additivity, forcing the measure on $Z^*$ to still be unique?

Comment: What seems to be missing is to show that a measure on $Z$ that extends the measure on $Z_0$ can itself be extended to a measure on $Z^*.$  What is the Caratheodory condition ? (I probably know it but not by that name.)